# How to avoid two switch?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class with two private methods:

```
export class LayerEditor {
       public layerManager: LayerManager;

       constructor() {
           this.layerManager = new LayerManager(this);     
       }
  
       private executeCommand() {
        switch (this.layerManager.editableLayer.type) {
            case LayerType.common:
                this.commandManager.set(new SelectExistCommand(this.reonMap));
                break;

            case LayerType.point:
                this.commandManager.set(new SelectExistPointCommand(this.reonMap));
                break;
        }
    }

    private createTools(): EditorTools {
        switch (this.layerManager.editableLayer.type) {
            case LayerType.common:
                return new CommonTools(new CommonToolsFactory());

            case LayerType.point:
                return new PointTools(new PointToolsFactory());
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid two switches no joining two methods in one switch? How to apply flexibility of OOP?

Class LayerManager manages a layers:

```
class LayerManager {
    public selectedLayer: TreeNode;
    public editableLayer: Layer;
    public polygonsArea: string;
    private readonly layers: TreeNode[];

    constructor(private layerEditor: LayerEditor) {
        this.layers = this.layerEditor.r.layersManager.editableLayers;
    }

    getLayers() {
        return this.layers;
    }

    selectLayer(layerId: string) {
        this.selectedLayer = { ...this.layerEditor.r.layersManager.getLayerConfig(layerId), enabled: true };
        this.layerEditor.r.state.changeTreeNode(this.selectedLayer);
    }

    createLayerObject() {
        this.editableLayer = FactoryLayer.create(this.selectedLayer.id, this.selectedLayer.type, this.layerEditor.r);
    }
}
```

Command manager class makes works with commands. This class works as dispatcher and stores all commands.

```
class CommandManager {
        public currentCommand: Command;
        protected commands: Command[] = [];
        protected undoCommand: Command;
    
        constructor(public layerEditor: LayerEditor) {}
    
        set(command: Command): void {
            if (command === this.currentCommand) return;
            this.currentCommand = command;
            this.commands.push(this.currentCommand);
        }
    
        execute(): void {
            this.currentCommand.execute();
        }
    
        undo(): void {
            this.currentCommand.undo();
        }
    
        redo(): void {
            this.currentCommand.redo();
        }
    
        cancel(): void {
            while (this.commands.length) {
                this.currentCommand = this.commands.pop();
                this.undo();
            }
        }
    
        complete(): void {
            this.currentCommand.complete();
        }
    }
```

If you need anything else I will post

Comment: OO better, by having two classes (inheriting/implementing from a superclass/interface) with their own execcuteCommand and createTools function implementations. Only switch "which object to make", after that, your code doesn't care what class it is, just that it can call .executeCommand and .createTools on it and the right thing will happen.

Comment: Thank you, could you share an sample, I got your idea, but I dont know which classes name I need to create and where to switch them in main LayerEditor class

Comment: I assume it should be class LayerPoint, class LayerCommon with methods inside createTools and executeCommand, but problem is that tools are refered to LayerEditor class, not for concrete layer.

Comment: Note that that's a very different problem. The naming is up to you, but I'd stick to something that tells people what the classes are. For instance, CommonLayerEditor and PointLayerEditor both extending/implementing LayerEditor, or even LayerEditor.Common and LayerEditor.Point (usually less good of a choice, but it depends entirely on your code conventions). As for the where: no way to tell from the code you're showing. Wherever you're building LayerEditors right now, though.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your `LayerManager` class as well (especially everything related to `.editableLayer.type`)? And what is `this.commandManager`?

Comment: I have posted, check out please

Comment: Ok, and what is `layerManager.editableLayer`, i.e. the `Layer` class? (I assume `type` is an enum, in that case you don't need to post it). It seems you could subclass layers of different kinds, and have each provide their own selection commands and tools. Unless you want to avoid that specifically, if you say a layer should not know how to edit itself. But regarding the `switch (this.layerManager.editableLayer.type)`, this seems like a violation of the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: Anyway somewhere I need to use switch to create a concrete objects, is not? Of Layer class

Comment: If `Layer` had abstract methods `getSelectionCommand()` and `createTools()`, which were overwritten in `CommonLayer` and `PointLayer` subclasses, you wouldn't need a `switch` statement but would only need to call the respective method of `this.editableLayer`. Then only the `FactoryLayer.create` would need to create layers of different types - or you continue the pattern and create different `TreeNode` subclasses that can create a specific layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is move all split decisions into one place. Instead of having many pairs of classes like `PointTools`, `PointToolsFactory`, `SelectExistPointCommand`, etc. you have one single `PointConfig`.  You want your two configurations to match the same `interface` as much as possible.  They both create a command and some tools.  Other classes should be able to use the returned tools interchangeably without caring if it is `PointTools` or `CommonTools`.  That way you can just call `this.config.createTools()`.

This is the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and the [C# Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) should be readable as it's extremely similar to TypeScript.  I've seen more of your code than what is posted here so I know that you were trying to do this already with a `class FactoryLayer`.  But you want to define it so that the factory is the **only** `switch` that you need.

It should be something roughly along these lines:

```
interface LayerConfig {
  id: string;
  type: SemanticLayerType;
  fields: Record<string, FieldConfig>;
  createTools(): Button[];
  createSelectCommand(map: ReonMap): Command;
}

class PointConfig implements LayerConfig {
  readonly type = SemanticLayerType.Point;

  readonly fields = {}; // fill this in

  constructor(public readonly id: string) {}

  createTools() {
    return []; // fill this in
  }

  createSelectCommand(map: ReonMap): Command {
    // fill this in
  }
}

class PolygonConfig implements LayerConfig {
  readonly type = SemanticLayerType.Polygon;

  readonly fields = {}; // fill this in

  constructor(public readonly id: string) {}

  createTools() {
    return []; // fill this in
  }

  createSelectCommand(map: ReonMap): Command {
    // fill this in
  }
}

class Layer {
  tools: Button[];

  constructor(public readonly config: LayerConfig) {
    this.tools = config.createTools();
  }

  // other stuff
}

export class FactoryLayer {
  static create(layerId: string, layerType: LayerType): Layer {
    if (layerType === LayerType.common) {
      return new Layer(new PolygonConfig(layerId));
    }
    if (layerType === LayerType.point) {
      return new Layer(new PointConfig(layerId));
    }
    throw new Error("Unknown Layer Type " + layerType);
  }
}

export class LayerEditor {
  public layerManager: LayerManager;

  constructor(private map: ReonMap, private commandManager: CommandManager) {
    this.layerManager = new LayerManager(map); //this);
  }

  private getCurrentLayer(): Layer {
    if (!this.layerManager.editableLayer) {
      throw new Error("No Layer Selected");
    }
    return this.layerManager.editableLayer;
  }

  private executeCommand(): void {
    // you could probably clean this up but you get the idea
    this.commandManager.execute(
      this.getCurrentLayer().config.createSelectCommand(this.map)
    );
  }

  public getTools(): Button[] {
    return this.getCurrentLayer().tools;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just tried to bring common things together. And trying to leverage Typescript features.

In both the private method you have `this.layerManager.editableLayer.type` common, now by adding an optional parameter and making use of  returning multiple datatype. Below is the updated code.
If need you can default parameter as `type = 'execute'` and whenever needed pass parameter as `create`

```
private checkTool( type?: string): EditorTools | void {

    const layerManagerType = this.layerManager.editableLayer.type

    switch(layerManagerType) {
        case LayerType.common:
                return (type === 'execute') ? 
                  this.commandManager.set(new SelectExistCommand(this.reonMap)) 
                  : new CommonTools(new CommonToolsFactory());
                break;
        case LayerType.point:
            return ( type === 'execute') ? 
              this.commandManager.set(new SelectExistPointCommand(this.reonMap)) 
              : new PointTools(new PointToolsFactory());
    }

}
```